# Excel: checking 2 lists to see if they contain values, and counting the number of times that they are paired with each other

Tags: arrays, excel, list, array-formulas, exists

I have 2 columns, with values that are paired with each other (col1 is A:A, col2 is B:B):

```
col1          | col2
Harry Potter  | Voldemort
Harry Potter  | Draco Malfoy
Michael Corner| Draco Malfoy
Ernie Mac     | Hannah Abbot
```

I want to check col1 to see if this name exists in List 1:

```
List1:
Harry Potter
Dumbledore
Ginny Weasley
Godric Gryffindor
```

I also want to check col 2 to see if this name exists in List 2:

```
List2:
Salazar Slytherin
Draco Malfoy
Voldemort
Severus Snape
Vincent Crabbe
```

Then I want the number of times where a Col1 name that exists in List1 was paired with a Col2 name that exists in List2.

This is my attempt so far:

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct(if(isblank(A:A),0,1), if(isblank(B:B),0,1), if(A:A=List1,1,0), if(B:B=List2,1,0)))
```

But it doesn't work. My suspicion is that something is wrong with if(A:A=List1,1,0) and if (B:B=List2,1,0).

Basically, I need col1 to be returned as

```
1
1
0
0
```

and col2 to be returned as

```
1
1
1
0
```

so then I can sumproduct them.
I tried to do countif col1 names exist in List1, initially, but countif returns a number not an array and just counts col1 as 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(List2)=B:B),INDEX(1+0*MUNIT(COUNTA(List2)),0,1)),
MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(List1)=A:A),INDEX(1+0*MUNIT(COUNTA(List1)),0,1)))
```

It's an array formula to be entered with Alt-Shift-Enter.

What a surprise, high school array algebra actually came in handy.  Improved by using COUNTA to get the size of the arrays.

[image: Excel]

Works fine in Google Sheets as well.

[image: Google Sheets]

Comment: The problem is my list sizes were just an example; the actual lists are bigger, and I actually have 20 lists to go through. So I can't use fixed sizes like MUNIT(5),0,1

Comment: @user3606790 - just use COUNTA instead of the fixed values to get the size of the arrays.  I've updated the formula.

Comment: `=arrayformula(sumproduct(
mmult(--(transpose(List1)=A:A, index(1+0*munit(rows(List1)),0,1))),
mmult(--(transpose(List2)=B:B, index(1+0*munit(rows(List2)),0,1)))))`

This returns a formula parse error

Comment: @user3606790 - It's an array formula to be entered with Alt-Shift-Enter.

Comment: `=arrayformula(sumproduct( mmult(--(transpose(List1)=A:A, index(1+0*munit(counta(List1)),0,1))), mmult(--(transpose(List2)=B:B, index(1+0*munit(counta(List2)),0,1)))))`
Also gets a formula parse error =\

Comment: @user3606790 - ARRAYFORMULA is a Google Sheets function, not an Excel one.  Your question specifically referred to Excel and the provided solution works in Excel.

Comment: @user3606790 - I cannot know what you are doing at your end, but it seems to be working fine both on Excel and Google Sheets at my end.

Comment: Hm mine is exactly the same, except that List1 and List2 are entire columns.
So in the formula it says (Transpose(D:D)=B:B)
The error now says: MMULT has incompatible matrix sizes. Number of columns in first matrix (1000) must equal number of rows in second matrix (95).

Comment: @user3606790 You should not be using the entire columns as the lookup array, that's why they were defined as named ranges List1 and List2.  It is possible to change the formula to use the entire columns as the lookup arrays but I really don't think it's a very wise thing to do.

Comment: Ok I changed it. I'm still getting the MMULT incompatible matrix size error, but I feel like I'm very close. Not sure what I'm missing
`=arrayformula(sumproduct(
mmult(--(transpose(Houses!B154:B178)='House Conflict'!A:A),index(1+0*munit(counta(Houses!B154:B178)),0,1)),
mmult(--(transpose(Houses!G154:G178)='House Conflict'!B:B),index(1+0*munit(counta(Houses!G154:G178)),0,1))))`

Answer (score -1):

For the first part, I suggest using VLOOKUP. Use the IF and ISNA functions to convert to 1/0.

1. Create two new columns, LU1 and LU2
2. In LU1, use vlookup to search each col1 entry in list1
3. In LU2, use vlookup to search each col2 entry in list2

For the second part, create another column and compare the entries in LU1 and LU2 to find which entries both have 1 for the value. Then just sum this column for the final count.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without creating new columns?
My lists were just examples, I actually have to go thru a lot of lists of varying sizes and I don't want to create new columns for every pairing